# How to exchange the format of arrays? - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

This is my json data:

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "code": "airtel121",
      "position": "manager",
      "salary": "25000",
      "login": {
        "id": 4,
        "username": "sameer",
        "firstName": "Mohamed",
        "lastName": "Sameer",
        "code": "airtel121",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My Expected output:

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "username": "sameer",
      "firstName": "Mohamed",
      "lastName": "Sameer",
      "code": "airtel121",
      "staffs": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "code": "airtel121",
          "position": "manager",
          "salary": "25000",
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

I want to exchange the first object into one array as staff, i dont know what kind of library or method is to make this stuff,

Comment: You can use this library https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr

Comment: Have you made any attempt(s) at all? What went wrong (and in what way)? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I dont made attempt, i looked for lodash library, but i did not found the method, if you can share the method name or post some piece of code, i can look into it and i will try and i post my attempt.

Comment: There is no such thing as a *JSON object*. If it's an `object`, it's Javascript. If it's JSON, it's a `string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this? You can use ES 2018 **Object spread** to pull the properties you want into an object literal.

```js
let a = {
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "code": "airtel121",
      "position": "manager",
      "salary": "25000",
      "login": {
        "id": 4,
        "username": "sameer",
        "firstName": "Mohamed",
        "lastName": "Sameer",
        "code": "airtel121",
      }
    }
  ]
}

let b = { "rows": [{ ...a.rows[0].login, "staffs": [ { ...a.rows[0] } ] } ] }

delete(b.rows[0].staffs[0].login)

console.log(b)
```

Comment: Converting circular structure to JSON, i am getting this.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to solve this problem. With simple javascript you can do it like this.

```js
var data = {
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "code": "airtel121",
      "position": "manager",
      "salary": "25000",
      "login": {
        "id": 4,
        "username": "sameer",
        "firstName": "Mohamed",
        "lastName": "Sameer",
        "code": "airtel121",
      }
    }
  ]
}

var exchangedData = data["rows"].map((row) => {
  row["id"] = row["login"]["id"]
  row["username"] = row["login"]["username"]
  row["firstName"] = row["login"]["firstName"]
  row["lastName"] = row["login"]["lastName"]
  row["code"] = row["login"]["code"]
  row["staffs"] = [{ id: row["id"], code: row["code"], position: row["position"], salary: row["salary"]}]

  delete row["login"]
  delete row["position"]
  delete row["salary"]
  return row;
})

console.log(exchangedData)
```

Comment: is there any way to do using any library? for short length of code?  for example, if i get more than 20 keys in my object? its very tough to code.

Comment: Yes, you can use normalizr library as mentioned above. Or can use  example shared by @connexo

Answer (score 0):

```
var rows = {
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "code": "airtel121",
      "position": "manager",
      "salary": "25000",
      "login": {
        "id": 4,
        "username": "sameer",
        "firstName": "Mohamed",
        "lastName": "Sameer",
        "code": "airtel121",
      }
    }
  ]
};

var data = {rows:[]}


rows.rows.forEach(function(value, index){

        data.rows.push(
    _.assign(
    {}, 
    {
      "id": value.login.id, 
      "username": value.login.username,
      "firstName": value.login.firstName, 
      "lastName": value.login.lastName,
      "code": value.login.code,
    },{"staffs":[{"id":value.id, "code":value.code, "position": value.position, "salary": value.salary}]})
)});

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a much simpler solution that handles any number of objects in your rows array.

```js
result = {
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "code": "airtel121",
      "position": "manager",
      "salary": "25000",
      "login": {
        "id": 4,
        "username": "sameer",
        "firstName": "Mohamed",
        "lastName": "Sameer",
        "code": "airtel121",
      }
    }
  ]
}


const data = result.rows.map(d => {
  const {id, code, position, salary} = d
  return Object.assign(d.login, {staffs: {...{id, code, position, salary}}})
})

console.log(data)
```

Comment: if i get many number of keys in object? is there any way to put keys dynamically.

Comment: Object.keys(result) will give you the keys of your object as an array. Is that what you mean?