# Return new form of arrays - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

My data:

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "code": "airtel121",
      "position": "manager",
      "salary": "25000",
      "login": {
        "id": 4,
        "username": "sameer",
        "firstName": "Mohamed",
        "lastName": "Sameer",
        "code": "airtel121",
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "code": "airtel121",
      "position": null,
      "salary": null,
      "login": {
        "id": 8,
        "username": "annamalai",
        "firstName": "Anna",
        "lastName": "malai",
        "code": "airtel121",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My expected outcome:

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "username": "sameer",
      "firstName": "Mohamed",
      "lastName": "Sameer",
      "code": "airtel121",
      "staffs": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "code": "airtel121",
          "position": "manager",
          "salary": "25000",
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "username": "annamalai",
      "firstName": "Anna",
      "lastName": "malai",
      "code": "airtel121",
      "staffs": [
        {
          "id": 7,
          "code": "airtel121",
          "position": null",
          "salary": null",
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried, but only i am getting first object, check my fiddle:

http://jsbin.com/qaqehakuwi/edit?js,output

Is this possible to loop using for loop or it can be done by lodash?

Check my above jsbin link for code.

I am using ES6 way of code in my project, so i used spread operator.

Comment: Didn't you already ask this same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52496180/how-to-exchange-the-format-of-arrays-javascript

Comment: yes but i got problem of object looping, so only again i am asking, this one is different problem.

Comment: I think then that you should unaccept that last answer and see if you can get a response

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exchange the format of arrays? - javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52496180/how-to-exchange-the-format-of-arrays-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` to create the `rows` array of the new object from the `rows` array of the old one:

```
let newObj = {
  rows: oldObj.rows.map(row => {                                     // map the rows of the old object into the rows of the new object
    let { login, ...rest } = row;                                    // for each object/row get the login object as 'login' and the rest of the props as 'rest'
    return { ...login, staffs: [rest] };                             // return a new object that has the props of 'login' and an additional prop 'staffs' which is an array containing 'rest'
  })
};
```

**Example:**

```js
let oldObj = {"rows":[{"id":3,"code":"airtel121","position":"manager","salary":"25000","login":{"id":4,"username":"sameer","firstName":"Mohamed","lastName":"Sameer","code":"airtel121"}},{"id":7,"code":"airtel121","position":null,"salary":null,"login":{"id":8,"username":"annamalai","firstName":"Anna","lastName":"malai","code":"airtel121"}}]};

let newObj = {
  rows: oldObj.rows.map(row => {
    let { login, ...rest } = row;
    return { ...login, staffs: [rest] };
  })
};

console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: is rest is ES6?

Comment: @MohamedSameer You're welcome! BTW, The first line is [objects destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) and it's an ES6 feature. The second line is a [spread syntax over objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) and it's a ES2018 feature. If the second line causes problems, you can use `Object.assign` instead like so: `return Object.assign({}, login, { staffs: [rest] });`.